# Symfony2 : get current directory error

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to get the current directory with :

`$this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/`

I've got this error : `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\XXX on line 124`

Code :

```
class AdminController {

/**
 * Add event controller.
 *
 * @param Request $request Incoming request
 * @param Application $app Silex application
 */
public function addEventAction(Request $request, Application $app) {
    $event = new Event();
    $types= $app['dao.type']->findAllSelectList();
    $eventForm = $app['form.factory']->create(new EventType($types), $event);
    $eventForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($eventForm->isSubmitted() && $eventForm->isValid()) {
        var_dump($event->getCoverImageLink());
        $file = $event->getCoverImageLink();
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        var_dump($fileName);
        //$path = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web';//$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
        var_dump($this);
        $app['dao.event']->save($event);
        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'The event was successfully created.');
    }
    return $app['twig']->render('event_form.html.twig', array(
        'title' => 'New event',
        'eventForm' => $eventForm->createView()));
}
```

How to fix this error please? What is the correct function to use?

Comment: Where did you place this code? The error message indicates that you didn't place the code in a class (or that the method you are working in is `static`).

Comment: Not only that but your code does not have $this->container in it.

Comment: I really don't know how to get this directory. what is the function to use?

Comment: I placed the code in this function, in a controller class :

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using `Silex`, not `Symfony 2`. Being a very minimalistic framework, silex doesn't give you all the configuration and dependency injection goodies that Symfony does.

The easiest approach to be able to retrieve the application root, would be to define it yourself in `bootstrap.php`. Simply add something like this at the top:

```
define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__ . '/../');
```

Now you can just use the constant in your controller:

```
public function addEventAction(Request $request, Application $app) {
    ...

    $path = APP_ROOT . '/../web';

    ...
}
```